# CAPTCHA disabled in Gitea Configuration

Tags: gitea

CAPTCHA for Gitea is not allowing me to enable

In my Gitea configuration as mentioned in the documentation there is an area called [SERVICES] to which you place your RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY & RECAPTCHA_SECRET as well as to enable CAPTCHA. I have all this in place but when logging into the administrator account in Gitea the CAPTCHA enabled is disabled and I don't know how to get it enabled. From what I understand there is no code I have to insert into any of Gitea pages therefore why is it not working ?